# Android: trouble in understanding wifi receiver and adapter concepts used to scan WiFi APs and list them in listview

Tags: android, adapter, android-adapter, android-wifi, wifimanager

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

// Declare View variables
private Button mRefreshButton;
private Switch mWifiSwitch;
private ListView mAPListView;
private List<ScanResult> mWifiList;
private List<String> mListOfProviders;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private WifiManager mWifiManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListOfProviders = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAPListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.APListView);
    mRefreshButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
    mWifiSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.WiFiSwitch);
    mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    boolean wasEnabled = mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
    if (wasEnabled){
        mWifiSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }
    mWifiSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    //wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
    mWifiManager.startScan();
    mWifiList = mWifiManager.getScanResults();

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{

}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

I am extremely new to Android development and simply building an android app to scan available APs and list them.

However, I am having a trouble in understanding concepts and usages of adapter and wifi receiver which are used most for building those functionalities.

Would you help me out what I should do to actually store and display the AP info after starting scanning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already created the `ListView` and generated the List of available connections, so most of your work is done. What is left to do is to fill the `ListView` with the objects in the list, to do that you need to use an Adapter.

But first you should add the names of the connections to the `List<String>` that you have created:

```
for ( ScanResult result :  mWifiList ) { 
 mListOfProviders.add( result.SSID); //This will add the SSID of the connection
}
```

And then you will pass this list to the `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mListOfProviders);
mAPListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added those two code blocks after getScanResaults and tested. But somehow it is not showing any result. any idea to fix it?

Comment: It was a problem of a permission. I am currently using Marsh mellow version. I figured out that there was an permission related issue with getting wifi signal results. From this version, it doesn't only require a wifi permission, but also a location permission. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :D can you please upvote or accept the answer if it helped ?